# How can I access audio files stored outside of var/www/html directory in apache server?

Tags: apache

I have some audio files in the location `/opt/tomcat6/webapps/msv2/uploaded_files` and some audio files in the location `var/www/html/audio_files`. I can access the audio files located in `var/www/html/audio_files` by `server_ip/audio_files`.How can I access the audio files stored in `/opt/tomcat6/webapps/msv2/uploaded_files`.

Comment: You have to setup aliases for the one at /opt/tomcat6

Comment: How can I do it? Can you provide me an example or documentation?

Comment: `Alias /uploaded_files /opt/tomcat6/webapps/msv2/uploaded_files`. make sure mod_alias is enabled

Comment: See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: Make sure to enable mod_alias first.

```
Alias /uploaded_files /opt/tomcat6/webapps/msv2/uploaded_files
```

See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html for more details.